# What is Dartdoc_options.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart, dartdoc

Could someone explain me what is and how to create the file `dartdoc_options.yaml` ? Because I can't understand what kind of file is. And I tried to launch `dartdoc`, but seems that this file must stay in the project and without it, dartdoc dosen't works..

Comment: `This file is used by dartdoc when generating API documentation for Flutter.`  you can find it [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/dartdoc_options.yaml)

Comment: and sorry, but it will be create by Flutter or I have to create it?

Comment: I'm not sure about it, you check pub.dev for it and the link I provided there from official doc

Comment: or it doesn't work or I wrong something..I had this file in my project, read the instructions and run dartdoc, but nothing changes..